# ec2+tomcat+mysql Access Denied!

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I'm running tomcat6 and mysql5 on a single ec2 instance and i cannot cannot from the outside world.

My context.xml on tomcat in ec2...

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-178.compute1.amazonaws.com:3306/data_dbo" />
    <property name="user" value="a_user" />
    <property name="password" value="a_password" />
</bean>
```

Client context.xml

```
 <bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/MyService-services/remoting/thingServiceExporter"/>
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.things.services.MyService"/>
    </bean>
```

Error on clinet...

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'domU-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-DB.compute-1.internal' (using password: NO)
```

I've setup privileges for my user but it doesn't seem to be using the user i setup in my tomcat datasource.  I say this because of the error on the client (Access denied for user ''@) no user, no password.  **Do i need to setup something between tomcat and mysql on ec2** because it seems to be using the internal dns to access MySql?

**Let me know if i can provide any other information!**

Comment: Have opened up the appropriate ports on your EC2 instance?

Comment: good question.  Yes, i've opened 8080.

Comment: ... and i can get an instance of the servlet connector.  I just can't do anything with it.

Comment: It's a long shot, but something like this? http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?81441-Mysql-Tomcat-java.sql.SQLException

Comment: Thanks for looking @Enno but, no this is not the problem.  It also works fine with a non-EC2 server that i have in my office that is of similar setup.  It seems like a configuration issue but i can't pin-point it.

Comment: Can you connect to mysql on command line using the same userid? Also, you have specified a password in context.xml but the log says "using password:no" are you expecting to login using a password or without?

Comment: I can connect fine over the cli with the user name and password. I am expecting the client to log in with the provided username and password but as you said it seems it does not.  The error also shows the internal dns name for EC2 not the one i provided in the servlet.  This is why I think this error is coming form the internal connection from Tomcat -> Mysql and not from my Client -> Tomcat.  Lastly the client doesn't connect to the DB at all it's all tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.  My persistance.xml had the following code...

```
 <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value=""/>
    </properties>
```

Not sure how that got in there!  The settings in the persistance.xml must override the settings in my Spring context file.